# Why doesn't the rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication is not working in my codes?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

My API:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication
"""A simple API for file upload."""
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FileUploadView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request):
        print "request:", str(request.META)
        print "request:", str(request.user.username)
        try:
            data = {'files': 'testing'}
            response = Response(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception when put file:", e
            data = { 'error' : str(e) }
            response = Response(data)

        return response
```

The above is my API views.py. I used postman to do PUT. I did not add anything in the header authorization (No HTTP_AUTHORIZATION in the request header), I can get **{'files': 'testing'}** as my response.

Why? Anything missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added authentication class but did not restrict access to your view. By default the DRF has unrestricted access . See the documentation section:

If not specified, this setting defaults to allowing unrestricted access:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
   'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
)
```

[Setting the permission policy](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy)